# How to create OR update a table from select SQL query ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table :

tabledate:

[image]

holiday_date :

[image]

query :

```
select (t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE) - count(c.HOLIDAY_DATE) - 2 * (to_char(t.END_DATE, 'WW') - to_char(t.START_DATE, 'WW')) as business_days, t.START_DATE,t.END_DATE
from tabledate t 
 left join
     holiday c
     on c.HOLIDAY_DATE between t.start_date and t.end_date and
       to_char(c.HOLIDAY_DATE, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american' ) not in ('Sat', 'Sun')
group by t.end_date, t.start_date
```

I'm trying to update all business_days rows from this query or create another table.

For example :

[image]

Comment: Do you need help writing the select or writing the update?

Comment: I need help writing the update

Comment: If your update is going to span every row I would create a new table using a `create table as select ...` using your current select statement (if it works) so that you bypass writing to the undo log. Afterward just drop the old table and rename the new table to that of the old table.

Answer (score 0):

If you need help writing the UPDATE WITH A SELECT

Basic Idea:

```
UPDATE table_date
SET business_days = (SELECT expression1
                     FROM table_holiday
                     WHERE conditions)
WHERE conditions;
```

COMPLETE:

```
UPDATE table_date t
SET business_days = 
        SELECT 
           ( t.END_DATE - t.START_DATE) 
           - count(c.HOLIDAY_DATE) 
           - 2 * (to_char(t.END_DATE, 'WW') 
           - to_char(t.START_DATE, 'WW')) as business_days
        FROM 
           holiday c
        WHERE 
            c.HOLIDAY_DATE between t.start_date and t.end_date 
        AND to_char(c.HOLIDAY_DATE, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american' ) 
            not in ('Sat', 'Sun')
```